# Laravel showing categories then on change show children

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-4

I want to show a list of categories which i can do no problem but on selection of one category show children that has that parent id of the selection.
So if JS/jQuery is the only or best option JS is not my strong point so I would like someone to give a good example so I understand more.

I have this in my model:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Categories');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categories','parent');
}
```

So just need a bit of help with the JS to show children on parent selection, please!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking several different questions here. To define relationships for an Eloquent model read here: [http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships). As far as getting children for a model, if you are using JS/jQuery you will want to set up a route that will return a JSON version of your model. You can get the children using the query builder as documented here: [http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

Comment: Yes i have all this etup it's more the JS i'm wanting help with

Comment: I just re-read your question and realized that, apologies. The second part of my response remains valid. You will want to created a route in Laravel to retrieve your data which takes the ID of the category selected as a param and then returns the child data as JSON. Returning the JSON data is simple, just call "toJson()" on the collection of found models. Take a look here for more information on retrieving data from the server using jQuery: [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Posted everything here -http://laravel.io/bin/1yWYn but it works, apart from when parent is selected then the child dropdown shows all categories instead of showing related to parent.

Comment: I believe this is caused because in your AJAX call you are setting the data sent to the server as `{ option: $(this).val() }` but in your route you are asking for `Input::get('parent')`. What you are doing in JS is sending the request with the `option` key set to your ID, but you are looking for it in the route on the `parent` key. Change the JS line above to `{ parent: $(this).val() }` and your problem should be solved. I would also recommend reading up on route params, as it might simplify your logic: [Laravel Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: I changed to this ````{ parent: $(this).val() }```` as you said and still doesn't work.

Comment: Modified my route slightly and now works - http://laravel.io/bin/2W933  but next question is how do i get the child dropdown to show in the html so i can grab its value to save to a database?

Comment: @Zane M. any idea's how to do this, so it shows up when I view source then I can grab it and save to a DB.